# gcc compile-time error sorting vector in a namespace

Tags: c++, stl

The following [MWE](http://ideone.com/w98C0P) fails to compile on (Cygwin) gcc 4.8.3 but compiles on MSCV 2010

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace Namespace
{
    struct Bar
    {
    };

    bool barComparator( Bar& bar1 , Bar& bar2 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    struct Foo
    {   
        void doStuff()
        {
            std::vector<Bar> barVec;
            std::sort( barVec.begin() , barVec.end() , barComparator );
        }
    };
}   

int main()
{
};
```

gcc error message

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/algorithm:62:0,
                 from Test007.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Namespace::Bar*, std::vector<Namespace::Bar> >; _Tp = Namespace::Bar; _Compare = bool (*)(Namespace::Bar&, Namespace::Bar&)]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2296:78:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Namespace::Bar*, std::vector<Namespace::Bar> >; _Compare = bool (*)(Namespace::Bar&, Namespace::Bar&)]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2337:62:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Namespace::Bar*, std::vector<Namespace::Bar> >; _Size = int; _Compare = bool (*)(Namespace::Bar&, Namespace::Bar&)]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5490:44:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Namespace::Bar*, std::vector<Namespace::Bar> >; _Compare = bool (*)(Namespace::Bar&, Namespace::Bar&)]’
Test007.cpp:20:61:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2263:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Namespace::Bar&’ from expression of type ‘const Namespace::Bar’
    while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))
                                   ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2266:34: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Namespace::Bar&’ from expression of type ‘const Namespace::Bar’
    while (__comp(__pivot, *__last))
```

I'd appreciate help on figuring this one out.

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/941852c67e792afb), [not gcc 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d09989a60ba9b780)

Comment: It works on my compiler as well. Judging from the error message, I would try changing the signature of the comparator to `bool barComparator(const Bar& bar1 ,const Bar& bar2 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [std::sort reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) says that the comparator function does not require `const &` reference arguments, but still must not modify the arguments.

It looks like your compiler is being a bit more restrictive and requiring
`bool barComparator( const Bar& bar1 , const Bar& bar2 )`.